# Why does my wpf form bind to internal resource?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resources, modifier

I have a wpf control, and a resource (marked internal) - both in the same namespace.

But when I try to access to the resource via

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApp7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp7"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Resource1.String1}" />
    </Grid>
   </Window>
```

I am getting a runtime XamlParseException. As soon as i make the resource public, everything works fine.

Am I forced to make the resource public to access it from xaml? In background c# code, all works fine.

EDIT:
The inner ArgumentException exception tells, that the static value "WpfApp7.Resource1.String1" cannot be resolved as enum, static filed or property.

Comment: What kind of resource is this? Where have you defined it? As you already have realized `x:Static` only references `static` properties, fields, constants and enumeration values.

Comment: Also in general the `Binding.Source` must be `public`.

Comment: It's normal resource file, which I created beside the xaml. (Add / new Item... / "Resources File") - Same path, same namespace. As mentioned, when setting modifier to public it works. however, both, xaml and resx, have the same namespace.

Comment: As I said before all binding sources as well as resources must be public. Double click the .resx file to open it in the resource designer. Now go to the drop down menu _Access Modifier_ and select _Public_.

Comment: The frameworks dependency property system which handles the bindings is not part of the client's assemblies. Internal types and members would be hidden from the framework.

Comment: Ok. Actually you could make this as answer. I did not know this. Maybe there is also a nicer work arround than making the resource public?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must understand, that `{x:static}` is a markup extention, which just being used to resolve the `Member` property at run time with XAML-services, which are placed in another assembly. See [x:Static Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/xaml-services/xstatic-markup-extension) on MSDN:

> You can make x:Static references to static fields or properties that
>   are not in the default XAML namespace for the current XAML document;
>   however, this requires a prefix mapping. XAML namespaces are almost
>   always defined on the root element of the XAML document.
>
> The lookup operations for static properties can be performed by .NET
>   XAML Services and its XAML readers and XAML writers, when they are
>   running with the default XAML schema context.

So the

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static local:Resource1.String1}" />
```

is the same as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static Member=local:Resource1.String1}" />
```

Since internal property can't be parsed the default error mesage about what the `Member` must be being thrown:

> The code entity that is referenced must be one of the following:
>
> - A constant
> - A static property
> - A field
> - An enumeration value
>
> Specifying any other code entity, such as a nonstatic property, causes
>   a compile-time error if the XAML is markup compiled, or a XAML
>   load-time parse exception.